# How to properly extend RxCocoa.Driver?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reactive

I’d like to extend `Driver<[String]?>` like this:

```
extension Driver where E == Array<String>? {

    var dashedLabel: UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        map({ $0?.joined(separator: "-") }).drive(label.rx.text)
        // yes, the above is never disposed
        // what I am interested about is this error:
        // Referencing instance method 'drive' on
        // 'SharedSequenceConvertibleType'
        // requires the types
        // 'SharedSequence<S, Optional<Array<String>>>.SharingStrategy'
        // (aka 'S') and 'DriverSharingStrategy' be equivalent
        return label
    }

}
```

When I extend it this way `extension Driver where S == DriverSharingStrategy, E == Array<String>?` the error disappears. Why do I have to constrain `S`, when `Driver` constrains it to `DriverSharingStrategy` already:

```
public typealias Driver<E> = SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, E>
```

```
public struct SharedSequence<S: SharingStrategyProtocol, Element> : SharedSequenceConvertibleType
```